# Can I use the Fonts in inkscape?

Tags: fonts, font-licensing

I made an educatoinal software.
I need the alphabet image using inkscape for my App.
There are many Fonts in Inkscape,
Can I use the Fonts in Inkscape without license?

Please answer... I'm eagerly waiting...

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Sorry but I'm having some difficulty understanding your question. What do you mean by "alphabet image"?  Inkscape uses fonts installed on your computer. They are not located in Inkscape. You can't use fonts in an app unless you have a suitable licence to use them in that way. Check the font licence. All fonts come with different licences. Also please don't ask legal questions here as they're off-topic. Ask a legal professional instead.

Answer (score 3):

Fonts are typically **not** part of any one application, but rather installed on the **operating system**. In other words, they aren't "Inkscape fonts". They are fonts Inkscape as detected are installed on your computer.

Most often operating system fonts have licenses which allow you to use them commercially.

**However**, if you've installed any other fonts on your system, you'll need to check the licenses associated with *those* fonts specifically.

There is *no* "one answer to rule them all". Each font can have its **own license** and you'll need to check those.

It's not possible to simply state *"yes, you can use them"* or *"no, you can't."*